# How to load a single plugin when starting vim from the cmdline

Tags: plugin-system

The situation: I want to use [vader.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim) to write some unit tests for a script of mine.

However to really test it, it would be best to only have my plugin and `vader.vim` loaded. I know how that you can use `vim -c 'your-commands-here'` via the cmdline. However when I try to use `vim -c 'set rtp+=my-plugin'` it simply does nothing. I feel like the whole bootup process is finished and *then* it gets added to the `rtp`, which is unfortunate.

So the question: How do I effectively whole plugins from the cmdline, *or* how do I *resource* my plugins in my rtp?

Comment: use custom vimrc to source those plugins and use `vim -u /path/to/custom_vimrc` ? if it still automatically loads plugins from `.vim/plugin`, try changing runtimepath as suggested in http://superuser.com/a/561470

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll accept it. Also found out you could do `vim -u <( cat <<< 'commands to be sourced' )` which works very nice

Comment: Recent versions of Vim (7.4.1384 and later) support packages and explicit loading of individual plugins.  See `:h packages` if you have Vim 7.4.1384 or later.  Beware that package handling has stabilized after version ~7.4.1500 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom vimrc to source those plugins and use

```
vim -u /path/to/custom_vimrc
```

or, as suggested by @hgiesel, use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```
vim -u <( cat <<< 'commands to be sourced' )
```